# Can't boot from USB stick on Dell Vostro 15 3000 (series 3591)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios, windows-installation

I have new LapTop Dell Vostro 15 3000 (series 3591) with factory installed Ubutnu 18.04. I would like to Install Windows 10 and I can't do that because **I can't boot from USB stick, I can't boot from Internal or external CD/DVD**.

- I double checked all options in BIOS. In boot options do not exist nothing like USB, CD/DVD.
- I have note in BIOS SETUP - Boot options: **Legacy Boot mode is not supported on this platform**. Only options that I have for boot is UEFI ST1000LM035-1RK172 WKPDM5LY and ubuntu.
- When I connect bootable USB stick with Windows installation or DWD with same installation, laptop can't boot from that device.
- I read all posts about that on google results for relevant keywords, and all posts on DELL support website.

Is any way to boot from CD/DWD or USB Stick, or some other idea to change OS?

Comment: You need to go to the UEFI boot options after rebooting **when the Win10 bootable USB stick is inserted.**  Then it will show up.

Comment: That is the problem. After that, I do not see USB stick in UEFI boot options.

Comment: You need an UEFI boot stick, not a BIOS one

Comment: Thanks @EugenRieck . Your post help me a lot. Job is done well. I will explain in details my steps in self answer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step guide (tested 100%)

1. On second Windows Laptop I installed program **Rufus** v3.12.1710
   from url: https://rufus.ie/
2. I made ISO from original Windows 10 pro installation DVD, with program **ImgBurn** from url: https://www.imgburn.com/
3. I put Windows ISO to USB stick with program Rufus. The following options for Rufus is very important:

- Device: **select the letter drive of USB stick**
- Boot selection: **Navigate to ISO of your installation**
- Image option: **Standard Windows installation**
- Partition scheme: **GPT**
- Target system: **UEFI (non CSM)**      <-- Very important
- File system: **FAT32 (Default)**      <-- Very important
- Cluster size: **16 kilobytes (Default)**
- Check Quick format and Create extended label and icon files
- Click the button START and wait... (Note: This will destroy all current data on youe USB Stick)

4. Put USB stick in laptop where you need to install and turn it on
5. After power on, click on F12 to show option boot order
6. **You can see USB stick** in boot options now and click it
7. PC will boot form USB stick and Windows installation will start normally.
8. Finish Windows installation and remove USB
9. That's all :)